# c++ link error, cannot find global.h struct

Tags: c++, windows, header, struct

I've defined a struct in a header file `global.h`, that i try to use it in a another class, but i get this error : `Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct tag_KG_Data g_GlobalVar" (?g_GlobalVar@@3Utag_KG_Data@@A) KGComThread.obj`

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tag_KG_Data
{
      int nKGStationID;
      int nKGComPort;

}GLOBAL_VAR;

#endif
```

and in `KGComThread.cpp` file i use it like this:

```
#include "global.h"

extern GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;
```

I think the compiler can't find the `global.h` file so it defines a meaningless `tag_KG_Data` struct, but i can't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
extern GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;
```

is only a *declaration*. The variable is not yet *defined*:

```
GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;
```

You need the previous line in a single implementation file.

Also, since this is C++, you don't need a tag for the struct, you can just write

```
struct GLOBAL_VAR
{
      int nKGStationID;
      int nKGComPort;
};
```

Comment: To clarify terminology: in `typedef struct X { ... } Y;` the `X` is the tag; the `Y is the typedef name.